# Can I send output of a Kafka Stream to a REST API endpoint

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I currently have an app that consumes from a Kafka topic using Consumer API and publish these messages to a REST API endpoint. I wanted to see if I can use Kafka Streams API do achieve the same. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking, yes, you can.   It would look something like this (with several details omitted for clarity)

```
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
KStream<String, String> inputStream = builder.stream("topic-name");
imputStream.foreach((key, value) -> {
      // Do something with key and value to publish to REST API
                    });
```

But this isn't what Kafka Streams was designed for; it's meant more for processing records from Kafka, producing the results back to Kafka, and not reaching out to external systems.

The biggest issue I see with this approach is that with Kafka Streams, you don't have direct control over committing.  I imagine you'd only want to commit after a bunch of records have been successfully sent to the REST API endpoint, including some retries, etc. So doing something like that is better served with a plain consumer application like you already have.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

There exists a Kafka Connect HTTP Sink plugin available online, which would be more optimized for this purpose.

Otherwise, if you control the code of said HTTP server, you could also chose to embed a Kafka Consumer within that.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a connector for this purpose:

https://github.com/castorm/kafka-connect-http